# How would I execute a class as non-blocking?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, nonblocking

I am creating a proxy that intercepts, decrypts, prints, and sends the packets to its original destination, however, I have a dilemma.. I execute `clienttoserver` just fine, but I then need to launch `servertoclient`, but in a non-blocking way.
There seems to be no resources, answers, or examples on how to do something like this, and since I can't, the script fails since it needs to receive a client packet, then a server packet, not just server packets as it wants to do.

NOTE:
I can **NOT** use threads, since they need to communicate data, and execute simultaneously.

Code Snippet:

```
class clienttoserver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ss = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.ss.connect(("place.server.end",1234))
        key = "<key>"
        self.cts = rc4.new(key)
        skip = 'a'*len(key)
        self.cts.encrypt(skip)
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.bind(('',1234))
        self.s.listen(500)
        self.client, self.addr = self.s.accept()

    def main(self):
        stcc = servertoclient()
        stcc.main(self.ss)
        while True:
            pack = self.client.recv(1500)
            decpack = self.cts.decrypt(pack[7:])
            print "Packet from Client"
            msgid = struct.unpack(">H",decpack[0:2])
            print "Msg ID: ",msgid
            print "Payload Len: ",decpack[2:4].encode("hex")
            print "Payload: ",decpack[7:]
            print ""
            self.ss.send(pack)


class servertoclient:
    def __init__(self):
        key = "<key>"
        self.stc = rc4.new(key)
        skip = 'a'*len(key)
        self.stc.encrypt(skip)

    def main(self, ss):
        while True:
            pack = ss.recv(1500)
            decpack = self.stc.decrypt(pack[7:])
            print "Packet from Server:"
            msgid = struct.unpack(">H",decpack[0:2])
            print "Msg ID: ",msgid
            print "Payload Len: ",decpack[2:5].encode("hex")
            print "Payload: ",decpack[7:]
            print ""
            self.client.send(pack)
```

--And my launch script;

```
import proxy
stpr = proxy.clienttoserver()
stpr.main()
```